# pass list of iterables to itertools function

Tags: python, python-itertools

i am  using the itertools.product function. i have a 2-deep nested list, which is a list of iterables. i want to pass this to product function dont know how to format it correctly.

to be clear, i want

```
In [37]: [k for k in product([1,2],['a','b'])]
Out[37]: [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

but generated from the a nested_list input like this

```
nested_list = [[1,2],['a','b']]
```

but instead i get

```
In [36]: [k for k in product(nested_list)]
Out[36]: [([1, 2],), (['a', 'b'],)]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`product` takes variable number of arguments, so you need to unpack your list.

```
list(product(*nested_list)) # without list() normally, of course
```

Comment: i did not know the concept of 'unpacking' a a list. thanks! is there a quick way to iterate over a list? like a builtin function to accomplish a list-comprehension, like the unpack operator?

Comment: @user366660: You use list comprehension to create a new list based on one or more already existing iterables (there's also generator expressions that do the same, but lazily; and set and dict comprehensions in Python 3). There are also `map` and `filter` functions, that do what they're named after. Normal iteration is done with a traditional `for` loop statement.